# Minutes and seconds as a variable in Python

Tags: python, time, ffmpeg

How can I store hours/minutes/seconds as variable in python?

For example:

```
time = "01:30" # 1 minute and 30 seconds
time2 = time + 10 seconds
```

Basically a program (using FFMPEG) will decide when to start playing an audio file but the value can be changed in +-10 seconds. The questions is how can I store this value?

To clarify my question: 
The time variable is "01:30" which clearly represent the time, 01 min 30 seconds.  How can I add 10 seconds to it to make the variable 10:40?  Clearly 01:30+:00:10 is not the solution.

Comment: What is your goal here, to work with time arithmetic? Either store time duration as seconds then (only convert to hours / minutes / seconds when printing the value), or use the `datetime` module.

Comment: This question needs more context

Comment: Do you want to randomly adjust the time by +/- 10 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store time as an integer representiong seconds *only*, then format that to the [ffmpeg time duration format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#time-duration-syntax) with a simple function:

```
def format_duration(seconds):
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    return '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds)
```

Demo:

```
>>> def format_duration(seconds):
...     minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
...     hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
...     return '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds)
... 
>>> duration = 170
>>> format_duration(duration)
'00:02:50'
>>> duration += 10
>>> format_duration(duration)
'00:03:00'
```

Comment: But current time doesn't play any role, since I'm trying to seek audio, I just need to change the variable.

Comment: @BadrHari: Then provide **that context** in your question, because that is not clear. What code are you using right now? This could well depend on the framework you are using to manage audio. Don't make everyone guess!

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I'm just using ffmpeg as subprocess in Python and I want to start converting a file from specific time let say 1 minute and 30 seconds, but I want to to be able to change that variable like adding for an example +10 or 20 seconds...

Comment: Deleting my answer since it does not make any sense given the newer info in the question.

Comment: THank you for your patience, that is what i needed and I also understand what I did wrong, thank you.